# PROLOG resolution traversal, visualize?

Tags: prolog, visualization

Is it possible, with reasonable effort, to visualize how PROLOG found the results to a query?
It would help to understand via which paths it found e.g. some repeating entries (e.g. finding a relative twice in a family tree query).

Comment: Usually, prolog interpreters have a debugger you can start preceding your clause with: -? trace.

Comment: btw, is there a good way to get rid of repeated results due to finding by more than one branch without breaking anything? If there Isn't anything elegant or predefined already, I guess I should make my own findall, which post-filters the result list for duplicates.

Comment: I have a meta-interpreter that creates an XML with all the node information and the edges. Then I use the file created in yED to visualise the derivation tree. Extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, the standard way to have an augmented pure Prolog interpreter is to augment a standard pure Prolog interpreter:

```ml
solve( T ) :-
  ( T = (A , B) ->  solve(A) , solve(B) 
  ; T = (A ; B) -> (solve(A) ; solve(B))
  ; T ).
```

We can use `copy_term/2` on each step, and collect the copied terms into a difference list:

```ml
solve( T, [Q|R], Z ) :- copy_term(T,Q), 
  ( T = (A , B) ->  solve(A,R,S) , solve(B,S,Z)
  ; T = (A ; B) -> (solve(A,R,Z) ; solve(B,R,Z))
  ; T,              R = Z ).
```

To be called as `solve( AQuery, PathTaken, [])`.

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

I can only find [prolog-graph](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prolog-graph) to perform simular task, but didn't try it yet. Authors claim that it *"generates images of resolution trees for given Prolog queries".*